# Show options depending on database records and previously selected options

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have two select blocks. The first one is the day of the week, the second one is time. In my phpmyadmin database I have a few recordings of day and time (Tuesday, 13.30; Friday 17.00 and so on). So the problem is how can I show only those time for a day as option that are not in database.

First user should select a day. If he selected a day, I record it in a variable and then show him the next select block. I've tried `!empty($_POST['day'])` but it doesn't work.

I don't understand how I am supposed to record select option value of the day (when user is selecting by clicking on it) to the variable (if user has selected Tuesday `$weekday = "tuesday"`, if Monday, `$weekday = "monday"`) so later I can compare it with recordings in database and skip if there is a recording for the same time of the same day.

I am iterating every half an hour from 9 AM to 11 PM

```
<select name="day" id="day">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="thurthday">Thurthday</option>
    <option value="friday">Friday</option>
</select>

<?php 
$weekday = "";
if(isset($_POST['day'])){
    $weekday = $_POST['day'];
}
if( !empty($weekday) ){ ?>
<select name="time" id="time"><?php
    for($i = 9; $i < 23; $i+=0.5){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option><?php
    }?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based admin gui written in PHP for managing MySQL databases. Your application talks to MySQL directly and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following what exactly you're trying to do and having problems with. It sounds like you want the option box for the time to only show the times that have been stored in the database, and that only after a user picks a day. So you'll have to generate the option dropdown (either dynamically or on another page load) based on the database results from the day dropdown. I'd use a query where you check for time from midnight (greater than or equal to) to midnight (less than) on the next day. I'd avoid DATE() because performance will suffer as it must compute for each one.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch, thanks for help. I'm willing to obtain all value except those, which have already been added to database. But it's not that important. In database I have 3 columns: id, day, time. More generally, how to hide (let's say `display: none`) all options for time, value of time and (previously selected) day of which is equal to existing in db.

Comment: I would dynamically (such as AJAX, etc) query the database when a user selects the day, then return all the results as an array. In PHP, you can add a check as part of your for loop as part of the "time" select, if the time exists in the array you would just skip printing the <option value... line. The downside would be if you have the potential to return a large number of results, but in your case there are only 28 possible values, so you should be fine. Anyway, there are probably a dozen ways to do this with various advantages or tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in script tags in my *.php file I've assigned a JavaScript variable with PHP value with all dates records from db like

```
<script>
    let optionsArr = '<?php echo variable_with_values_from_db ?>'
</script>
```

And then I can check everything using JavaScript and getting change possible variants in further inputs